# What is the difference if we specify path with in [] and without []?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

What is the difference if we specify path with in [] and without []?

- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]

Comment: Judging by the name of the field with [] you can put more than one root-ca thanks to [] that indicate the parser that the contents contain multiple value. (Separated by coma probably).

Comment: A little example : `YAML.load "---\n:a: [test, things, 2]\n"` => `{:a=>["test", "things", 2]}`